# What does the recent: 'additional protection against phishing', from Google do?

Tags: gmail, privacy, phishing

Recently Gmail has been showing a prompt to use: "additional protection against phishing".

It looks like it only matters if I use Chrome or Android.  I normally use Linux and Firefox and I do not see any explaination about what it (might) do or what benefits it offers?

I hope the collective has some insight.  Is this just another way to track or fingerprint GMail users?  *Thanks in advance*

Comment: Do they \give any explanation in their own documentation?

Comment: @SolarMike Short non-informaton about chrome or android